# How do I instantiate and access boost mpl types?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

So I've built my `boost::mpl::map` object which contains some mixture of keys and types. I now want to instantiate an instance of the map such that I have an instantiation of each `type` in the map:

```
using namespace boost::mpl;
using MyMap = map<
  pair<int, double>,
  pair<double, double>,
  pair<bool, int>>;

int main()
{
  // create the map:
  MyMap myMap;
  // now I want a reference to the element indexed by "int"
  using RefType = at<MyMap, int>::type&;

  RefType myRef(myMap); // compile error!
}
```

The error I'm getting is something along the lines of:

> error: cannot convert 'MyMap {aka map<...>} to blarghh {aka int}

Clearly I should be getting some sort of "index" value (maybe `boost::mpl::map::order`?). So how does one actually access (ie get references to) elements in these associative `mpl` containers? Also, where is the documentation for how this (sepcifically) is done?

Answer (score 0):

Your code had a few problems:

- No #includes.  Missing `<boost/mpl/at.hpp>` is a problem here.
- No commas between the pairs in the map.
- You're trying to create a map as a value, which doesn't make sense.  I'm not sure what to make of `MyMap myMap`.  You don't usually instantiate MPL types.

This code works, hopefully it's roughly what you want.

```
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>

using namespace boost::mpl;
using MyMap = map<
  pair<int, double>,
  pair<double, double>,
  pair<bool, int>>;

int main()
{
  using RefType = at<MyMap, int>::type&;

  double foo;
  RefType myRef(foo);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the missing commas. I want to instantiate the map such that I have a set of all `types` instantiated, then I want a reference to one of the values (for the sake of this example). The `std` equivalent might be creating an instantiation of a `tuple` and getting a reference to one of its instantiated types. Does this make sense? Your example, as I understand it, just creates a double and a reference to it.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I need boost fusion for this? In that case, my next question is; how do I convert my `boost::mpl::map` to a `boost::fusion::map` that I can then instantiate?

Comment: What is the higher-level goal you're trying to accomplish?  I'm having a hard time understanding why you would want a map of `{type: default-constructed-other-type}`.